# create plot first, then add inside a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a small function for my own work. However I would like to create something like porting existing plots into figures. Which goes like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as PLT
ax1 = PLT.plot(array1)
ax2 ...

def multi_ax(array_of_ax ):
  fig = PLT.figure()
  for n in range(some_number):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(x,y,n+1)
    ax.replacing(array_of_ax[n], postions_of_array)
```

Is there way to fit this way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you precisely want to do, it is rather hard to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to move an `axes` from one figure to another; the axes is linked to the figure upon creation.

Instead, you'll have to first generate the figure, and then the `axes`es within that figure.

Comment: Great, I think I don't have any regret to continue my work. So to make it short, there is no hope for creating "axes" before placing in "figures"?

Comment: Indeed. Maybe if you do a whole lot of fiddling with matplotlib's internal workings, but it wasn't built to be able to do that.